# Codeigniter - Why adding to cart didn't work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart, cart

I have a problem, when I try to add cart to shopping cart. Cart cannot enter to shopping cart.

And this is my controller:

```
public function buy($product_id)
    {
        $product = $this->m_produk->find($product_id);
        $data = array(
                        'id'      => $product->id,
                        'qty'     => 1,
                        'nama'   => $product->nama,
                        'harga'    => $product->harga
                        );

        $this->cart->insert($data);
        redirect('produk/index');   
        }
```

This is my model to add cart:

```
public function find($id){
    $hasil = $this->db->where('id',$id)
                      ->limit(1)
                      ->get('produk');
    if ($hasil->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $hasil->row();
    }else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<?php

foreach ($produk as $product) {

?>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="<?php echo base_url(''.$product->gambar);?>" width="200" height="200" class="img-rounded center-block" alt=""/>
<div class="caption">
<h4 class="text-center"><?php echo $product->nama?></h4>
<h4 class="text-center">RP.<?php echo $product->harga?>,00</h4>
<!-- <a href="#"  class="link-class btn btn-primary center-block" role="button">add to cart</a> -->
<?=anchor('produk/buy/'.$product->id,'add to cart' , [
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary' , 'role' => 'button'
]) ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

PS: when I `print_r` my content, cart just displays: `array()` its means when I add cart, cart cannot enter to shopping cart.

Can anyone solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: can give me solution for this problem ?

Comment: what your `insert()` function looks like?

Comment: @marius i dont understand about you mean , can you be specific about that insert() function ?

Comment: @RickyKurniawan `$this->cart->insert($data);` i believe this line is responsible for inserting the items into the DB ? if it fails to insert - thats the reason you cannot see the shopping cart updates? You could copy and paste a code from that method. It would give more information

Comment: Can you please edit your question to improve the grammar. I tried fixing it but on some places I don't even know what you are trying to say.

Comment: @marius so , can you give me more specific , how to fix that ?

Comment: @user8 oke , i already edit my question to improve the grammar

Comment: @RickyKurniawan , can you show us what `$this->cart->insert($data);`  code does? where do you define `$this->cart` and that the `$this->cart` object's method `insert` looks like?

Comment: @marius   $this->cart->insert($data) is query from codeigniter to Adding an Item to The Cart. source:https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per documentation you have referred to:
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html

> Important: The first four array indexes above (id, qty, price, and name) are required. If you omit any of them the data will not be saved to the cart. The fifth index (options) is optional. It is intended to be used in cases where your product has options associated with it. Use an array for options, as shown above.

Please pass all the required parameters. 
You have got `name` misspelled or missing, `price` missing